# How to loop through an array and use the value to try and find an object name

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was writing to see if I can manipulate jquery arrays.

So I have an object:

```
myobject = {
   abc : {
      value      : 'abc',
      template   : '<div class="abc"></div>',
   },
},
```

Now what I have is another array that looks like this:

```
myarray = ["abc", "cde"];
```

So what I am trying to do is loop through `myarray` to see if it matches an object in the `myobject`.

Now I thought you would accomplish this by doing something like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < myarray.length; i++) {
   if (myobject.myarray[i]) {
      // do something
   }
}
```

Now this gives me an error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined`

So clearly this isn't the approach, how can I loop through `myarray` to see if `myobject` has an object that matches the name from the `myarray` array?

Comment: `if(myobject[myarray[i]])`

Comment: Also see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4968406/javascript-property-access-dot-notation-vs-brackets

Answer (score 2):

The problem within your code is, that `myobject.myarray` does not exists, so `0` of a non object is not available. Try to check with [in](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in):

```
for (var i = 0; i < myarray.length; i++) {
   if (myarray[i] in myobject) {
      // do something
   }
}
```

Comment: I like this, as it's easy to log if there isn't ever a match. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can treat a javascript object la dictionary.

[Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors)

```
myobject = {
    abc: {
        value: 'abc',
        template: '<div class="abc"></div>',
    },
},
myarray = ["abc", "cde"];
for (var i = 0; i < myarray.length; i++) {
    console.log(myobject[myarray[i]]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the object reference from `myobject.myarray[i]` to `myobject[myarray[i]]`

```js
var myobject = {
   'abc' : {
      value      : 'abc',
      template   : '<div class="abc"></div>',
   }
};


var myarray = ["abc", "cde"];


for (var i = 0; i < myarray.length; i++) {
   if (myobject[myarray[i]]!=undefined) {
      console.log(myobject[myarray[i]]);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do the following.

```js
for (var i = 0; i < myarray.length; i++) {
   if (myobject.hasOwnProperty(myarray[i])) {
      // do something
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You were close with iterating through the array to look for the match, to finish use `hasOwnProperty` to check if the current place in the array matches any property in `myobject`

```
var myobject = {
    abc: {
        "value": "abc",
        "template": "test"
    }
}

var myarray = [ "abc", "cde" ];

for (var i = 0; i < myarray.length; i++) {
    var thisKey = myarray[i];
    if (myobject.hasOwnProperty(thisKey)) {
      //match found
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jessikwa/obpacbao/3/